# Common JSON Call class

Tags: javascript, json

```
var JsonClientPatientSearch = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    // API Url to call
    var url = GetAPIUrl() + "PatientSearch";
    JsonClientPatientSearch.open("POST", url);
    //setting Request Header
    JsonClientPatientSearch.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      JsonClientPatientSearch.send(PatientSearch(PatientSearchCriteria,Credentials,Header));    

    JsonClientPatientSearch.onload = function(){

    };
    JsonClientPatientSearch.onerror = function(e){

    };
```

I have a lot of JSON calls in my project, is it possible i can write a class and use its instance to make the JSON Call... just passing the parameters...

Comment: A "class" in Javascript is not possible. But you can do workarounds to create "objects" that might help you.  Take a look at: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create instances of objects and reuse them. Your code would look something like this:

```
var MyCall = function(url, onLoad, onError){
    // API Url to call
    this.url = GetAPIUrl() + url;
    this.onLoad = onLoad;
    this.onError = onError;
};
MyCall.prototype = {
    call: function(){
        var JsonClientPatientSearch = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        JsonClientPatientSearch.open("POST", this.url);
        //setting Request Header
        JsonClientPatientSearch.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        JsonClientPatientSearch.send(PatientSearch(PatientSearchCriteria,Credentials,Header));    
        JsonClientPatientSearch.onload = this.onLoad;
        JsonClientPatientSearch.onerror = this.onError;

    }
};

// create callbacks
var myLoad = function(response){ /* do something with response */ },
    myError = function(error){ /* do something with error  */ };
// create instance
new MyCall("PatientSearch", myLoad, myError);
// do a call
MyCall.call();
```

You'll need to tweak this according to how this needs to work with your other global objects. But hopefully this should send you in the right direction.

Comment: Where should i write onLoad and onError function and how would i recieve the responseText

Comment: sorry, if forgot to include callbacks...i have edited the example

Comment: if you can, I would probably recommend to use a library for your ajax calls though.

Answer (score 2):

Why not save the trouble of writing an own AJAX framework when you can use e.g. the excellent jQuery library?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/